# Projection of vector into an axis, along a direction

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently learned how I can project a vector $\overline{a}$ onto another one $\overline{b}$. I was wondering how I could achieve the same effect, but project the vector $\overline{a}$ along a direction. For example, in this [image], we can see that the direction of the projection is the axis $\overline{b}$ normal. This I know how to do. What I really wanted to do, is that the projection was made in the direction of the vector $\overline{a}$ normal.
While searching, I found something about Thales Theorem, but I have no clue of how I could use it to my advantage. If someone could enlighten me, I would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: I want to get the vector $\overline{a3}$:
[image]

Comment: If you know how to project a vector onto another vector, and you want to project a vector along a direction, why not just take a vector in that direction, and then project onto that vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first projection, the one you know, you want the dot product $\langle a_1, a_2\rangle$ to be $0$, where $a_1 = \lambda b$ and $a_2 = a-\lambda b$. This yields $\lambda = \frac{\langle b,a\rangle}{\langle b,b\rangle}$ as you know.

In the second case, you want $\langle c,a\rangle=0$, where $c=\lambda b-a$. This yields $\lambda = \frac{\langle a, a\rangle}{\langle b,a\rangle}$ and hence
$$
a_3 = \lambda b = \frac{\langle a,a\rangle}{\langle b,a\rangle} \, b.
$$

Comment: I look into this and try to figure this out. It will take me some time. I'll leave a comment if I am able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So the projection of a vector $\overline{a}$ onto a vector $\overline{b}$ is $\frac{\langle \overline{a},\overline{b}\rangle\overline{b}}{|\overline{b}|^2}$.

Comment: OP says he/she already knows that, right?

Comment: Yes, this I know. I edited the post to show exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a_1 + a_2 = a$ so once you have the projection $a_1$ then $a_2=a-a_1$ and you can project onto that vector in the usual way.

Comment: How can this help me to get the vector $\overline{c}$ (depicted in the edited post) ?

Answer (score 0):

Projection of $\bar a$ onto $\bar b$ is $\frac{<\bar a, \bar b> \bar b}{\|a\|_2} $ and if you want to project onto hyper plane perpendicular to $\bar b$ then it is $\bar a - \frac{<\bar a, \bar b> \bar b}{\|a\|_2}$

Comment: But is that what OP wants to do? That's not at all clear to me.

Comment: I don't understand this answer either. It seems that you are explaining to me how I can achieve the projection shown on the image above. What I want to do, is to take $\overline{a}$, project onto $\overline{b}$, along the direction of a vector $\overline{c}$, where $\overline{c}$ is normal to $\overline{a}$.

Comment: Updated post makes things clear thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, vectors $a$ and $b$ are given, and you want a vector $c$ such that $c$ is orthogonal to $a$ and such that $a+c$ is parallel to $b$. As equations, that's $a\cdot c=0$ and $a+c=kb$ for some real number $k$. So we get $a\cdot(a+c)=a\cdot kb$, which is $a\cdot a+a\cdot c=ka\cdot b$, which is $a\cdot a=ka\cdot b$, which is $k={a\cdot a\over a\cdot b}$, so finally $$c=kb-a={a\cdot a\over a\cdot b}b-a$$

Comment: In a comment you write that you want $c$, which I've given, but in the question you say you want $a_3$, which is $a+c$, which is $kb$, which is ${a\cdot a\over a\cdot b}b$.

Comment: You are right, that comment is wrong. It shouldn't be $\overline{c}$ but $\overline{a3}$.
I will chew on this and try to figure this out and the above answer by Cristoph as well. Thank you.